# Trigonometry - What does this calculation do?

Tags: math, trigonometry

I've encountered the following math in some graphics-related code:

```
// get the angle between 2 points
double d = Math.atan2(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);

// wtf?
d = (8 * (d + PI + 0.25^2 * PI)) / PI;
```

Can anyone with a mathematical intuition help explain what this does in "practical" terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line does what it says. d is the angle between both points as seen from the origin.

The second line depends on the meaning of the `^` operator (language isn't specified). Assuming ^ means power, I get (hope I did it correctly, please check for yourself):

```
d = (8 * (d + PI + 0.25^2 * PI)) / PI;
d = (8 * (d + PI*17/16))/PI
d = (8*d + 8*PI*17/16)/PI
d = (8*d + PI*17/2)/PI
d = 8*d/PI + 17/2
```

I guess `PI` is what it normally is (`3.141...`), it looks like a transformation from radiants to some other form (where 16 is a full circle or 360°). The addition of 17/2 then would translate to 'add 191,25° to the angle' (which is slightly more than the opposite direction).

I don't know why anyone would do that, nor do I know why he didn't transform the expression to the simple form (which btw should evaluate faster unless the optimizer does a really good job).